# how to scroll layout with view pager in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I just try to do scroll my activity in which **tab + view pager** but i m not getting success. Below i show what happened when i'm using scroll.

**shown view pager image and xml code**

[image]

**not scroll vertically now**

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_user_banner_profile_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/shown_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/banner" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <biz.xicom.defindme.profileuser.TabPageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs_bg"
                android:fillViewport="true" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#f1eee7"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**not shown viewpager bcz im add view pager on scrollview but i dnt now why ding this**

[image]

**now not shown anything which is on view pager when add view pager on scroll view**

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_user_banner_profile_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/shown_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/banner" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <biz.xicom.defindme.profileuser.TabPageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs_bg"
                android:fillViewport="true" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#f1eee7"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**scrolling but viewpager height fixed now you see what happend**

shown view pager

[image]

**now u see below image with scrolling and have u see scroll which i point**

[image]

```
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_user_banner_profile_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/shown_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/banner" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <biz.xicom.defindme.profileuser.TabPageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs_bg"
                android:fillViewport="true" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100000dp"
                android:background="#f1eee7"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i want above thing to do but without fixed `(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  android:layout_height="100000dp")`. So how can i achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

You add ScrollView in that layout where you add/inflate the content of layout.If you use Fragment than keep ScrollView in FragmentLayout instead of ViewPager layout.